# Endless pageload getting data from repository (doctrine) in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've used symfony console to create multiple entities having manyToOne and oneToOne relations. Nothing special, just a normal setup. When I `var_dump($this->userRepository->find($id)->getAddresses()); die;` I get an endless pageload showing objects in objects.

I'm not sure where to start debugging to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal.
var_dump doesn't protect against circular references. So if you have an entity A, having B, and B having A, you get an infinite loop basically.
Use dump instead, it's provided by symfony.